# Magento 2 : Is there any way to resize product page image using Phtml instead of view.xml

Tags: magento-2.1

I just need to change image size which is showing into product page. but whenever i change that image size from etc/view.xml then other image url also changed so Is there any way to resize product page image using Phtml instead of view.xml